# Cookie showing alert after move on next steps(page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm using the Stepper for Register process (like this: step-1...to, step3) which every step is a different page in bootstrap4.

When a page load Cookie alert will be showing. But after the close it (stored into local storage) or will be removed after 10 Seconds. when will I move to the next step (step-2), Cookie alert will be again showing. Actually don't want to show it again (if once closed it) till the end (last step).

Is there a way to handle this issue? Below mentioned the code I'm using right now. Please help.

```
$(function () {
  if (getCookie('BlockPop') == null || (getCookie('BlockPop') != undefined && getCookie('BlockPop').toLowerCase() != 'true')) {
        setCookie('BlockPop', 'true', 30);
        $('.popuphome').slideToggle(1000);
        $('.close').click(function () {
            setCookie('BlockPop', 'true', 30);
            $('.popuphome').slideUp(1000);
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.popuphome').slideUp(1000);
        }, 30000);
    }
});

function setCookie(ckname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = ckname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(ckname) {
    var name = ckname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `!= undefined` is not how to check if something is undefined, sadly. So change that condition to

```js
typeof getCookie('BlockPop') !== 'undefined'
```

Next up, your full if statement essentially says "if the BlockPop cookie is null or if it is defined and has the value `'true'` then ..."

I'm not sure how the code guarded by your if statement will **not** be executed.

I think you'll get the desired effect if you change the condition to be

```js
if(getCookie('BlockPop') === '')
```

Because now you're checking if the cookie is empty, and then you will set it. `getCookie` returns an empty string for an undefined cookie, so you don't need to check for `null` or `undefined`.

Once it's set you'll not call the rest of the code for 30 days. The time parameter (`exdays`) of `setCookie` is the number of days until the cookie expires, so it will last far more than 10 seconds.

If you want the cookie to expire after 10 seconds, then change the code in `setCookie` that sets the expiry to:

```js
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 1000));
```

And call `setCookie` like:

```js
setCookie('BlockPop', 'true', 10);
```

Comment: As per your suggestions, tried using  'typeof getCookie('BlockPop') !== 'undefined'' and  'if(getCookie('BlockPop') === '')' but still facing same issue, cookie alert agin showing when move on second step.

Comment: If your timeout for clearing the cookie is 10 seconds, then it will clear after ten seconds, so if you go to the next page after ten seconds the popup will happen.

Comment: Actually issue with 'path', finally, it's solved.
Thanks for your help.

'var domain11 = "path=/";'
'document.cookie = ckname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + ";" + domain11;'

Comment: @Siddharthpanchal cool! you should write up your solution as an answer in case other people have a similar problem :D